markdown mode gives error (invalid-read-syntax "?" 1176 26)
When calling markdown-mode I get this error (invalid-read-syntax "?" 1176 26). The backtrace is as follows:
  read(#<buffer  *load*>)
  edebug--read(read #<buffer  *load*>)
  apply(edebug--read read #<buffer  *load*>)
  #f(advice edebug--read :around read)(#<buffer  *load*>)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "/home/****/.emacs.d/lisp/markdown-mode.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 55253
  load-with-code-conversion("/home/****/.emacs.d/lisp/markdown-mode.el" "/home/****/.emacs.d/lisp/markdown-mode.el" nil t)
  autoload-do-load((autoload "markdown-mode" "Major mode for editing Markdown files.\n\n(fn)" t nil) markdown-mode)

At that time if I switch to buffer *load* it shows the following, with the cursor is on the first ^, between â and ž.
(defcustom markdown-url-compose-char
  (cond
   ((char-displayable-p ?âˆž) ?âˆž)
   ((char-displayable-p ?â€¦) ?â€¦)
   (t ?#))
  "Placeholder character for hidden URLs.
Depending on your font, some good choices are â€¦, â‹¯, #, âˆž, â˜…, and âš“."
  :type 'character
  :safe 'characterp
  :package-version '(markdown-mode . "2.3"))

This is the version I have:
;;; markdown-mode.el --- Major mode for Markdown-formatted text -*- lexical-binding: t; -*-

;; Copyright (C) 2007-2017 Jason R. Blevins and markdown-mode
;; contributors (see the commit log for details).

;; Author: Jason R. Blevins <jblevins@xbeta.org>
;; Maintainer: Jason R. Blevins <jblevins@xbeta.org>
;; Created: May 24, 2007
;; Version: 2.3
;; Package-Requires: ((emacs "24") (cl-lib "0.5"))
;; Keywords: Markdown, GitHub Flavored Markdown, itex
;; URL: https://jblevins.org/projects/markdown-mode/



The first step is to upgrade to the latest markdown-mode: it is available from MELPA and it is version 20240829.324 (as of this writing). Then check if there is still a problem.

Upgrading to Package-Version: 2.6 from MELPA solved it.
